# Hear Vs hear from

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Should hear be followed by the preposition **from** in this question?

Why have just one best friend to discuss your passions with when you can have at least two and hear different opinions **"from"**?

Answer (score 1):

You could have

> Why have just one best friend to discuss your passions with when you
> can have at least two **to** hear different opinions from?

Or, as Kate Bunting notes:

> Why have just one best friend to discuss your passions with when you
> can have at least two and hear different opinions from **them**?

It does not necessarily follow that different friends will always have different opinions about everything.

Comment: The original sentence sounds odd without also adding **them**. As Michael says, they won't necessarily have different opinions, so you could include _maybe_ or _perhaps_.

Answer (score 0):

While Michael Harvey gives a good overview of the grammar, let me give you the distinction between the two variants you thought of:

- **hear someone** is typically applied in most literal sense: having sound enter your ears; there is also the use where it means receiving an opinion, "I hear you" can both mean "our audio connection is good enough for me to understand your voice" and "I acknowledge your point". But depending on context, it may be unclear which one you mean.
- **hear from someone** is about receiving communication. It doesn't need to be audio - you can hear from your friend over an email or text messages; it's never about audio quality - it is about receiving meaningful communication.

So you'd hear opinions from them, but you'd hear how they talk their opinions over your head while you tune them out...